# Unable to change UITableView backgroundColor, separatorStyle, or anything

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I am running into this issue where I have a uitableview inside a uiview, which I put into another uiview, but I am unable to change the background color of the tableview. I ran into this issue the other day and completely rewrote the class, which worked, but now I am trying to make another table (I even copied and adjusted the functioning code), but for whatever reason, I can't change the background color of this tableview. I stripped it down to try and figure out what is going on, so there isn't much there, but I can see the tableview is showing up (via the debug heirarchy), I just can't change it's color.

```
import UIKit

class PersonTableView: UIView {
    var people = [Person]()
    
    private let foodTableView: UITableView = {
        let foodTableView = UITableView()
        foodTableView.register(FoodItemTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: FoodItemTableViewCell.identifier)
        foodTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        foodTableView.backgroundColor = .green
        return foodTableView
    }()
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.setupElements()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setupElements() {
        self.addSubview(foodTableView)
        foodTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        foodTableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        foodTableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        foodTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        foodTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
}


import UIKit

class FoodItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier = "FoodItemTableViewCell"
    var food: FoodItem?
    
    let contentWrapper = UIView()
    let foodTitleLabel = UILabel()
    let foodPriceLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupElements()
    }
    
    func update(for food: FoodItem) {
        self.food = food
        setupFoodElements()
    }
    
    func setupElements() {
        self.contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true;
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "secondaryBlue")
        
        contentWrapper.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "complementaryOrange")
        contentWrapper.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        contentView.addSubview(contentWrapper)
        contentWrapper.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentWrapper.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        contentWrapper.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        contentWrapper.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.width - 20).isActive = true
        contentWrapper.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
    }
    
    func setupFoodElements() {
        foodTitleLabel.text = food?.name
        contentView.addSubview(foodTitleLabel)
        foodTitleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        foodTitleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24.0)
        foodTitleLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
        foodTitleLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        
        foodPriceLabel.text = "$\(food?.price ?? 0.0)"
        contentView.addSubview(foodPriceLabel)
        foodPriceLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        foodPriceLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24.0)
        foodPriceLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
        foodPriceLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please could you share some code on how you set up PersonTableView ?

Comment: Adding the other classes also might help with debugging like FoodItemTableViewCell for instance.

Comment: @ShawnFrank 
` let personTableView: PersonTableView = PersonTableView() `

Comment: @ShawnFrank Also, I added FoodItem TableViewCell

Comment: I added a possible solution below. If this still does not solve your issue, maybe add some more code on how you you initialize this TableView class. Is it done in another UIView subclass or from a UIViewController. Which function do you call it from - this might help one of us further debug your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I set up everything as you did and most things seem to be set up right in terms of the custom UITableView and UITableViewCell classes.

The only thing I suspect is that when you initialize your UITableView using `let personTableView: PersonTableView = PersonTableView()` in the other view / view controller - this table view is not laid out properly using either autolayout or frames.

This is what I did in the viewDidLoad() of a view controller using your classes above:

```
        // Initialize the custom UITableView like you did
        let personTableView = PersonTableView()
        
        // Add the UITableView inside another view like you said
        // This view is part of the UIView controller
        view.addSubview(personTableView)
        
        // Set the AutoLayout constraints of the UITableView with respect to the view
        // it is contained in
        personTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        personTableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        personTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        personTableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        personTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

After doing this, I could see the green TableView

[image: Adding custom UITableView to a view hierarchy]